# Is it possible to create a spin-box like widget in python tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am making a file manipulator in python-idle. One of the abilities is to create a file. When creating this file however - unless specifically stating in the name the type of file (like .txt for a text file) it is saved as a file that cannot be viewed from outside the program. I would like a spin-box like widget that would have 2 types - .txt and .docx  . I would like the name to be shown in the widget.

Comment: If there are only two choices, why a spinbox? Why not a combobox, optionmenu, or just a couple of radiobuttons?

Comment: First I don't know what a combobox is. Second I what is ready for more options in the future - like pdf. The window is quite big already and there is almost too many radiobuttons ;) ... I just like the sound of a spinbox. @BryanOakley

Comment: [Combobox](https://tkdocs.com/widgets/combobox.html)

Comment: Combobox is exactly what I need @BryanOakley . But how to do it in idle? Last time I attempted methods like the ones in the example I just got errors.

Comment: This is just for saving a file? If so why not use tkinter's `filedialog`? https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog

Comment: I don't use IDLE, but that's irrelevant. You create a combobox pretty much like any other widget: `from tkinter import ttk; ... cb = ttk.Combobox(...)`

Comment: @PNX Read up on [The Tkinter Spinbox Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm) and [Tutorial - Spinbox](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#spinbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want a "spin-box like widget", but from the comments it sounds like a combobox meets your needs.

Here's a basic example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")
label = tk.Label(root, text="file type:")
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=(".txt", ".doc"), state="readonly", width=8)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cb.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of combobox]

Comment: @PNX I just pasted this example into an IDLE editor on Windows and it ran fine, the same as when run from a command line.